# When booting from USB, how can I leave grub and boot to hard drive?

Tags: grub2, usb, live-usb

After booting to a live USB (I normally use Multiboot or persistent), I enter to the grub which is installed in the USB flash drive.

At USB grub, is there a way to boot to the hard drive?

As I can access the command-line from the USB grub (by pressing "c"), can I type something to boot to the hard drive?

Comment: You need to explain what do you intend to do. I doubt anyone can understand what you're asking as it is.

Comment: Do you want to add a menuentry to the USB's grub to boot the internal drive?

Comment: If you are using a USB stick with a Full install, just boot the drive, open terminal and do a "sudo update-grub", this should add any OS's on the internal drive to the USB's grub. Not so easy with a Persistent USB drive, probably easiest to copy grub menuentries from an updated Full install if it is a grub2 type Persistent install per mkusb.

Comment: @MichaelBay  when we press "c" we go to command line on grub. Can we type something there that boot to hard drive?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I updated my question. I normally use multiboot or persistent.

Comment: If you press an arrow key on the purple screen before GRUB, it has on option to boot from the first hard disk

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? If you have grub on sda5 for example: `configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` But that has to be a working system.

Comment: The first menu item when I boot a MultiBootUSB drive is "Boot from Hard Disk", Selecting this will boot the internal hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With Syslinux type** USB boot drives such as MultiBootUSB, MultiBoot USB, Unetbootin, etc make there is generally an option in the boot menu to Boot the First Hard Drive.

**With Grub2 type** USB boot drives such as mkusb and the original MultiBootUSB make, a menuentry to boot an internal drive can be added to the USB's grub.cfg located on the usbboot partition:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (16.04) (on /dev/sdxy)'  {
    insmod part_msdos
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root uuuu-uuuu-iiii-dddd
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic root=UUID=uuuu-uuuu-iiii-dddd ro quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
}
```

If Windows is the OS on the internal drive it is beyond the scope of this answer.

**With a Full install** type USB boot drive, open terminal and  run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it will add any OS's on the other drives of your computer including Windows.